# Identify which face of a cube is up

Tags: sensor, prototyping, gyro

I have a device whose shape is a cube and I need to identify in real time which face is up.

My current solution is (not yet implemented) is to use a gyro to get angular variation, but I can see 2 problems:

- Which face is up when the cube is "powered up"?
- We can't assume that every 90° variation will change the face standing up. If is a variation in the "world" Z axis, the face remains the same. But the "world" Z axis is not equals to the gypo Z axis.

There is any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need a 3-axis accelerometer?

Comment: Or 6 metal-ball style tilt sensors?

Comment: @Wouter, is there actually such a thing? Couldn't find it.

Comment: Mercury switches?

Comment: @Sherby for instance www.mouser.com RBS040110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gyro won't tell you anything useful, at least not the kind of electronic gyro you can afford.  It sounds like what you want is an accelerometer. One for each axis lets you find the complete acceleration vector, which will be just gravity when the cube is still.  There are units with three accelerometers, each orthogonal, integrated into one device.  Search for *"3-axis accelerometer"*.

If the cube is being jostled about, the acceleration vector won't point exactly up, but mostly it will.  Unless someone is deliberately whacking this thing or tossing it around, the acceleration vector will point upwards well enough.  You can even detect the in-flight case, since the acceleration vector will be zero then.

Comment: Would a gyro not potentially be useful, if also an accelerometer is used to compensate for inertial drift?

Comment: Agreed. I would put a 6-axis motion IC on there. You would of course use the accelerometer for the base data as Olin said but the gyro would certainly help in signal processing for situations where the cube is tumbling or even to compensate for drift as you said.

Comment: I agree.  A 3-axis accelerometer is the way to go.  Just for reference, Atmel has some very affordable dev kit add-ons with accels, gyros, and magentometers (http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/sensors_xplain.aspx).  I have no affiliation with Atmel...just thought these were relatively affordable solutions relevant to the question.

Comment: @Phil: The small and cheap electronic gyros inherently sense turn rate instead of position as mechanical gyros do.  You have to integrate that to get angular position, which accumulates errors quickly.  After a few seconds, the position is pretty much useless.  If the OP really needs to know up even during short disturbances, then gyros might help.  Otherwise, 1 g accelleration due to gravity is larger than what you normally experience.  I won't work perfectly on a roller coaster, but does that really matter?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree, depends on application requirements. That's different though, then saying "a gyro won't tell you anything useful".

Comment: Since I don't have a accelerometer right now, I wrote an Android app using my smartphone accelerometer to test. And it worked!